# Clearing all elements in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

I am trying to clean up a `TicTacToe` board represented by a 2-dimensional array and have written the following code:

```
public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    final int ROWS = 3;
    final int COLUMNS = 3;

    public static char[][] board = new char[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    // Creates a new board
    private static void newBoard(){

        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (j < 3){
            while (i < 3){
                board[j][i] = null;
                i++;
            }
            j++;
            i = 0;

        }
    }
    }
}
```

But for some reason I receive the errors

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
    - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
     EnumHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
```

The error is on the line "private static void newBoard(){"

If anyone help me understand these error messages and how to correct them, it will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I changed the method so it uses a nested loop instead, but i still receive the errors

Comment: `board = new int[3][3]` better?

Comment: Post the code of entire class.

Comment: Which lines do these messages refer to?  And how is board defined?

Comment: @moonwave: That might avoid the syntax error, but would incur a runtime error (since the valid indices would be 0..2, while the loop ranges over 1..3).

Comment: The error message is unrelated to the code you're showing. But array indices start at 0 in Java. Not at 1. And you should have two nested loops.

Comment: @JB Nizet: It is certainly workable as a single loop; in fact, if OP addressed your point about indices, the rest of the structure would work fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter: no. It would be an infinite loop, because i and j are never incremented. I know it's doable in a single loop. It's just much more natural and safe with nested loops.

Comment: i and j are incremented?

Comment: @JBNizet I'd even represent the board as 1-dimensional array. Also, there's no 2-dimensional arrays in Java...

Comment: @Tarlen. Execute the code manually in your brain,and write the value of i and j at each step, and you'll understand. Two nested for loops would be much easier. EDIT: i was NOT incremented at the time I wrote this comment. The OP has now edited the code.

Comment: You can't assign null to a char

Comment: sorry i edited a little before i saw your comment, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put all definitions inside `main` method. Java syntax doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're missing a close-bracket somewhere, but the code you posted looks right, so I'll guess that it's a close-bracket right ABOVE what you've posted.

Also, this doesn't answer your question, but I can't help but point out that you've got a static function (newBoard) operating on a member variable (board).  To make this compile your board must also be static.  This is a habit that will bite you when you start doing concurrency, because you could have two different processes working on the same board.

Comment: I just posted my whole class now, no missing brackets as far as i can tell. And I did as you said, but now i receive the error "Illegal modifier for parameter board; only final is permitted" on the line of the array declaration

Comment: I put the rest of your class, and I took the "static" modifier off your newBoard function, and I changed null to 0 (and added some debugging code to the main), and it compiled and ran.

Comment: The static thing is what I was talking about before.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable.

Comment: The 0 is because char can't be null.  You need to define what it means to have an empty space on the board, possible using a compile time constant (eg: final http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables)

Comment: Note that, as Sarge Borsch suggests, I changed the "main" function.  If this helps, please up-vote and accept at least one (or both) of our answers.